# Usage of „Erhöhung bei der Anzahl“

Tags: preposition, genitive

The phrase *Erhöhung der Kopfläuse* in my sentence was corrected to include the preposition and noun *bei der Anzahl*:

> Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren, ich melde mich in diesem Gremium zu
> Wort, um **die Erhöhung bei der Anzahl der Kopfläuse** in unseren Schulen
> hervorzuheben.

Which meaning of the preposition *bei* is intended and is “*die Erhöhung der Kopfläuse*” actually wrong?

Comment: (1) What is actually raised or increased? Certainly not the head lice themselves, right? But it is more likely the **number** of head lice. (2) The preposition *bei* is optional here. It is also correct to say *die Erhöhung der Anzahl der Kopfläuse*.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich - You mention that _bei_ is optional.  What meaning would it add when it is included?

Comment: It seems to me this is an error in logic/meaning instead of German syntax. The English version of the original "...to highlight the increase in head lice in our schools." has the same problems as pointed out in the answer and other comments. It might work informally, but since it is (apparently) a formal setting this kind of ambiguous wording is questionable at best.

Comment: @RDBury, I agree. I even thought about flagging the question as off-topic for this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe the example with money is more common...
*"you had 3 dollar now you have 4."* your money didnt increase.(because it cant, its not specified how exactly its meant...) the amount of money you have did increase.

its just like in programming...
or anything rly:
*"a human cant increase"*, but the human has height, age, fingernail lenght hairlength and so on, and so on. these properties can increase.

> Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren, ich melde mich in diesem Gremium zu Wort, um die Erhöhung bei der Anzahl der Kopfläuse in unseren Schulen hervorzuheben.

but that sentence itself wouldnt be commonly used. better would be:

> Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren, ich melde mich in diesem Gremium zu Wort, um das vermehrte Auftreten von Kopfläusen an unseren Schulen hervorzuheben.

and it also goes around the "anzahl" thing :D
also "an" is better than "in" in those contexts.